# Question about injective functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Let $S$ and $T$ be sets and let  $f : S \to T$ be a function. Prove the following:
>
> If $U$ is a set $g:T\rightarrow U$ is a function such that $g \circ f$ is injective then also $f$ is injective

Approach: All I know is that if $g \circ f$ is injective then for $x,y \in S$, if $(g \circ f)(x)=(g\circ f)(y)$ then $x=y$. I feel like this doesn't tell me anything about the function $f$. How can I approach this?

Comment: If $f$ fails to be injective, what does that mean? What would happen to $g \circ f$?

Comment: it wouldn't be injective anymore. I drew a picture but I don't know if that's enough

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$, then $g(f(x))=g(f(y))$, this implies $x=y$ (because $g\circ f$ is injective). So $f$ is injective.

Comment: Right, I was thinking if I can go backwards once I get directly to $x=y$, so I can conclude that $f(x)=f(y)$ then f is injective

Comment: A function is injective if $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$. So we assumed $f(x)=f(y)$ and proved that $x=y$ :) Did it help?